# Get bluetooth devices connection notification

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, bluetooth

I'm making a winform application that monitors things happening on the computer like processes, wifi, screenshots,... and I'm working on Bluetooth connection.

I need to get the notification when a Bluetooth device connects or disconnects to the computer (or laptop), for example mobile phones. In addition, I need something to identify the device like ID or just the name of it if possible.

One thing to notice, I'm using C# and it's a winform app, it would be nice if the solution uses Windows native library (like winapi, pInvoke). Third party library is fine but it would be my last choice.

---

Update: I've followed Rita Han's answer and got some results.

Below is my code inside the override WndProc method. It works totally fine with USB but not with Bluetooth devices.

While the app is running, I turn on Bluetooth on both my laptop and mobile phone but they have not paired yet → the function gets called and it says Bluetooth came, then I connect the two devices → now they are connected but no notification except the one above.

After that, while they are connected, I try to remove the mobile phone device, they are disconnected and I connect them back again and one more time I get no notification about a new Bluetooth connection has been scanned or connected.

So in short, I get notified when Bluetooth radio scans for a new device but not when connecting in the first time. After that, disconnecting and reconnecting do not give me any notifications also.

Am I missing some events?

```
case USB.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:

    devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);
    if (devType == USB.DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
    {
        USB.DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol;
        vol = (USB.DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(USB.DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

        // Get the drive letter 
        c = USB.DriveMaskToLetter(vol.dbcv_unitmask);
        listBox1.Items.Add("New USB has come with name " + c);

    }
    else if (devType == BluetoothDeviceNotification.DbtDevtypDeviceinterface)
    {
        BluetoothDeviceNotification.DevBroadcastDeviceinterface vol;
        vol = (BluetoothDeviceNotification.DevBroadcastDeviceinterface)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(BluetoothDeviceNotification.DevBroadcastDeviceinterface));
        listBox1.Items.Add("Bluetooth came GUID " + vol.ClassGuid + "\t Name: " + vol.Name);
        break;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: StackOverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service. Show us what you have try so far? Do you have some [search attempts](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) or [code samples](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)?

Answer (score 2):

For using Windows native API you can use [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationa) function.

Refer to "[Registering for Device Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/registering-for-device-notification)" sample for getting started.

[Bluetooth interface GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-bthport-device-interface):

```
GUID BluetoothGUID = {0x0850302A, 0xB344, 0x4fda, 0x9BE9, 0x90, 0x57, 0x6B, 0x8D, 0x46, 0xF0 };
```

[Bluetooth and WM_DEVICECHANGE Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wm-devicechange-messages).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Please see my update above for the problem I've encounted while following the answer
Hope you can help me

Comment: @CườngNguyễnHùng I can get `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message when connecting or moving the device on Windows 10 1903. What's your Windows version?

Comment: It's window 10 Pro 1607

Comment: @CườngNguyễnHùng I test SensorTag and mobile phone, both trigger WM_DEVICECHANGE event when connecting and disconnecting. Can you try higher version than 1607?

Comment: That's the problem. My winform application will be running on serveral laptops which means different Window versions. I need to get the events no matter which Window version is. It would be nice to see your code.

Comment: @CườngNguyễnHùngc I use the same code on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/registering-for-device-notification). You can use that code in a simple win32 c++ application and have a try to see if it helps.